# Как в symfony обратиться к БД из статического класса?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Я создал статический класс внутри Symfony (без зависимостей самого Симфони) и хочу работать в нём с БД, используя Doctrine. Также у меня есть entity таблицы в БД и репозиторий для этого Entity.

Как я понял, мне не хватает ContainerInterface, который автоматически есть в генерируемом Symfony контроллере, но у меня нет контроллера.

Мануалы подсказывают мне, что есть вот такой способ:

```
/** @var FramePagesRepository */
protected $framePages;

public function __construct(FramePagesRepository $framePages) {
    $this->framePages = $framePages;
}
```

Но он уже выглядит слегка костыльно и требует динамически создаваемого класса, а у меня статический. Можно ли как-нибудь полностью отвязать работу с БД от структуры Симфони и обращаться к Репозиторию таблицы напрямую?

Скорее всего, в силу малого опыта мой подход неверен в целом, поэтому опишу ситуацию целиком:

У меня есть symfony и websocket сервер Ratchet, работающий вне структуры Синфони, который общается с html страничкой. Сервер запускается с помощью запуска php скрипта через крон.

Comment: Ну так избавьтесь от `static` и заинжектите `EntityManager` через конструктор.

Comment: Я понимаю, это самое простое решение. Но класс используется в нескольких десятках мест, и делать столько работы совсем не хочется, если есть способ лучше.

Comment: А иначе вам придется еще больше работы сделать. 1. Изменить Kernel.php, чтобы создать синглтон инстанса кернела. 2. В статической функции получить инстанс кернела. 3. Из инстанса кернела получить контейнер. 4. Из контейнера получить сервис доктрины. 5. Из сервиса доктрины получить EntityManager 6. Из EntityManager получить репозиторий. И все это вместо того, чтобы просто инжектить свой класс (сервисом он станет автоматически по умолчанию) и вызвать его метод. Оно вам надо?

Comment: А как заинжектить класс через __construct, если класс всё-равно должен вызываться через new? Инъекция же не будет работать?

Comment: Можно, конечно переделать скрипт запуска сервера вебсокета на Symfony Console и заинжектить FramePagesRepository в нём, а далее передать этот репозиторий как параметр в __construct класса вебсокет сервера, который передаст этот репозиторий в __construct метод переделанного из статического в динамического класса (из-за которого начался вопрос), а после использовать FramePagesRepository уже в нём, но это даже на словах звучит перебором.

Comment: Можно, конечно, передавать не репозиторий, а EntityManager, чтобы была возможность использовать другие репозитории и чуть повысить удобство, но не будет ли это даже в таком конфиге страшным костылём на всём коде? Неужели нет способа проще, чтобы не продевать всё это друг через друга?

У меня есть ещё два класса, которые вызываются друг из друга, а они, собственно, вызываются из класса вебсокета, туда возможность работы с базой тоже нужно будет таким способом передавать?